# What "types" of reward are promised for keeping particular Mitzvos?

Tags: mitzvah

Trying to generalize [Alicht's question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103669/common-denominator-of-the-mitzvot-whose-reward-is-lengthened-days). Although the Mishnah in Avos states that we don't know the [true] reward of keeping Mitzvos:

> "וֶהֱוֵי זָהִיר בְּמִצְוָה קַלָּה כְבַחֲמוּרָה, שֶׁאֵין אַתָּה יוֹדֵעַ מַתַּן שְׂכָרָן שֶׁל מִצְוֹת."
>
> And be careful with a light commandment as with a grave one, for you did know not the reward for the fulfillment of the commandments.

we can find that "lengthened days", for example, is explicitly mentioned by the Torah for honoring parents or sending away the mother bird.

What additional types of reward does the Torah (and Nac"h) promise for keeping particular Mitzvos?

I would like to make a summary table, categorizing Mitzvos into those where the reward is not mentioned, and those where it is mentioned and what it is.

*THis question is not about rabbinical speculations and conclusions, like "בזכות מצוות צדקה זוכים לבנים יפים".*

Answer (score 4):

Using the *mitzvot* mentioned in [this entry](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=57246&st=&pgnum=678) of Kovetz Yesodot v'Chakirot as a guide, I arrived at the following list of *mitzvot* which have their reward (possibly) mentioned explicitly by the Torah.

1. *[Kibbud Av v'Em](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.20.12?lang=bi)* (Shemot 20:12)

   > כַּבֵּ֥ד אֶת־אָבִ֖יךָ וְאֶת־אִמֶּ֑ךָ לְמַ֙עַן֙ יַאֲרִכ֣וּן יָמֶ֔יךָ עַ֚ל הָאֲדָמָ֔ה אֲשֶׁר־יְהוָ֥ה אֱלֹהֶ֖יךָ נֹתֵ֥ן לָֽךְ׃‏
   >
   > Honor your father and your mother, that you may long endure on the land that the LORD your God is assigning to you.
2. *[Tzedakah](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.15.10?lang=bi)* (Devarim 15:10)

   > נָת֤וֹן תִּתֵּן֙ ל֔וֹ וְלֹא־יֵרַ֥ע לְבָבְךָ֖ בְּתִתְּךָ֣ ל֑וֹ כִּ֞י בִּגְלַ֣ל ׀ הַדָּבָ֣ר הַזֶּ֗ה יְבָרֶכְךָ֙ יְהוָ֣ה אֱלֹהֶ֔יךָ בְּכָֽל־מַעֲשֶׂ֔ךָ וּבְכֹ֖ל מִשְׁלַ֥ח יָדֶֽךָ׃‏
   >
   > Give to him readily and have no regrets when you do so, for in return the LORD your God will bless you in all your efforts and in all your undertakings.
3. *[Hashavat 'Avot](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.24.13?lang=bi)* (Devarim 24:13)

   > הָשֵׁב֩ תָּשִׁ֨יב ל֤וֹ אֶֽת־הַעֲבוֹט֙ כְּבֹ֣א הַשֶּׁ֔מֶשׁ וְשָׁכַ֥ב בְּשַׂלְמָת֖וֹ וּבֵֽרֲכֶ֑ךָּ וּלְךָ֙ תִּהְיֶ֣ה צְדָקָ֔ה לִפְנֵ֖י יְהוָ֥ה אֱלֹהֶֽיךָ׃‏
   >
   > You must return the pledge to him at sundown, that he may sleep in his cloth and bless you; and it will be to your merit before the LORD your God.
4. *[Shiluach HaKen](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.22.7?lang=bi)* (Devarim 22:7)

   > שַׁלֵּ֤חַ תְּשַׁלַּח֙ אֶת־הָאֵ֔ם וְאֶת־הַבָּנִ֖ים תִּֽקַּֽח־לָ֑ךְ לְמַ֙עַן֙ יִ֣יטַב לָ֔ךְ וְהַאֲרַכְתָּ֖ יָמִֽים׃‏
   >
   > Let the mother go, and take only the young, in order that you may fare well and have a long life.
5. *[Mezuzah](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.11.20?lang=bi)* (Devarim 11:20-21)

   > וּכְתַבְתָּ֛ם עַל־מְזוּז֥וֹת בֵּיתֶ֖ךָ וּבִשְׁעָרֶֽיךָ׃ לְמַ֨עַן יִרְבּ֤וּ יְמֵיכֶם֙ וִימֵ֣י בְנֵיכֶ֔ם עַ֚ל הָֽאֲדָמָ֔ה אֲשֶׁ֨ר נִשְׁבַּ֧ע יְהוָ֛ה לַאֲבֹתֵיכֶ֖ם לָתֵ֣ת לָהֶ֑ם כִּימֵ֥י הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם עַל־הָאָֽרֶץ׃‏
   >
   > And inscribe them on the doorposts of your house and on your gates to the end that you and your children may endure, in the land that the LORD swore to your fathers to assign to them, as long as there is a heaven over the earth.
6. *[Talmud Torah](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.11.19?lang=bi)* (Devarim 11:19,21)

   > וְלִמַּדְתֶּ֥ם אֹתָ֛ם אֶת־בְּנֵיכֶ֖ם לְדַבֵּ֣ר בָּ֑ם בְּשִׁבְתְּךָ֤ בְּבֵיתֶ֙ךָ֙ וּבְלֶכְתְּךָ֣ בַדֶּ֔רֶךְ וּֽבְשָׁכְבְּךָ֖ וּבְקוּמֶֽךָ ... לְמַ֨עַן יִרְבּ֤וּ יְמֵיכֶם֙ וִימֵ֣י בְנֵיכֶ֔ם עַ֚ל הָֽאֲדָמָ֔ה אֲשֶׁ֨ר נִשְׁבַּ֧ע יְהוָ֛ה לַאֲבֹתֵיכֶ֖ם לָתֵ֣ת לָהֶ֑ם כִּימֵ֥י הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם עַל־הָאָֽרֶץ׃‏
   >
   > And teach them to your children reciting them when you stay at home and when you are away, when you lie down and when you get up ... to the end that you and your children may endure, in the land that the LORD swore to your fathers to assign to them, as long as there is a heaven over the earth.