# What's the heter for g'vinas akum?

Tags: halacha, dairy, leniencies, bishul-akum, rav-joseph-ber-soloveitchik

In [a comment elsewhere on the site](/posts/comments/25546), [Curiouser](/u/1627) writes:

> the heter for gevinas akum (based on Tosfos) was paskened l'masseh by R. Solovetichik, among others

or, in other words, Rabbi Soloveitchik, among others, ruled as a practical matter leniently regarding *g'vinas akum* (otherwise kosher cheese that was produced by non-Jews), and this ruling was based on [*Tosafos*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tosafot).

- What was the leniency? I mean, the prohibition of *g'vinas akum* is a well-established one, and I'm sure Rabbi Soloveitchik (and the others) didn't do away with it altogether based on a *Tosafos*: I assume that, rather, they said it doesn't apply in some circumstances. What circumstances?
- What's their support (from *Tosafos* and/or elsewhere)?
- Which Rabbi Soloveitchik is this?
- Who are the "others" and what, if any, authorities have argued against this leniency or indicated one should not rely on it (at all, or to the extent Rabbi Soloveitchik and the others do)?

Comment: This may be too many disparate questions in one and (if so) I should split it up into separate question posts. If you think so, please vote to close it as "too broad" or comment indicating your opinion.

Comment: It's explicit that G"A is all about the use of non kosher rennet (shulchan aruch). When the production if the cheese is under full hashgocha by a trustworthy Jewish certification agency, why wouldn't there be room for leniency?

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I don't know what you mean by "full hashgocha". If it's under full-time _hashgacha_ then that already fulfills the requirements of _g'vinas Yisrael_ (_Rama_), so what's the _chidush_ of Rabbi Soloveitchik _ud'imeh_? And if it's not full-time _hashgacha_ and the leniency is that that's sufficient, then maybe there is room for leniency, as you put it, but "why wouldn't there be" is a bit much: it's certainly a _chidush_.

Comment: I believe I've heard he eventually reversed his position.

Comment: Maybe tosfot was referring to cheese made with animal tenet and r solivetchik was referring to cheese using plant rennet but not using cholov yisroel milk. The concept being that non kosher milk won't become cheese.